# How to refresh view panel in Sencha?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

This seems elementary, but I need to be able to refresh a view after a Web Service call.

The data on the screen is not tied to a store because it is dynamically built at runtime.

Here is my view:

```
Ext.define('CAMSApp.view.OpBuyoffView', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: ['widget.opbuyoffview'], //ToDo Use I18N 
    config: {
        xtype: 'panel',
        cls: 'dialogview formview',
        centered: true,
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        modal: true,
        screenId: 'opbuyoffview',
        id: 'opBuyoffTableContainer',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'center',
        },
        defaults: {
            minHeight: 46
        },
        items: [
        {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        docked: 'top',
        title: 'Buyoffs',
        cls: 'grey-bold-34pt',
        ui: 'transparent',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'grey-bold-40pt greyBtn',
            text: 'Close',
            idForAction: 'opbuyoff-cancel_btn',
        },  {
            xtype: 'spacer',
        }],
        },
        {   id: 'opBuyoffToolbar',
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'left',
            },
            items: [
            {
               xtype: 'button',
               cls: 'blueRoundedBtn',
               text: 'Buyoff',
               idForUpdate: 'opbuyoff-buyoff_btn',
               disabled: true
            },

            { xtype: 'spacer',
              minWidth: 480
            }]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'label',
                style: 'border:1px solid black',
                cls: 'opBuyoffTableHeader',
            },
            id: 'tabOfBuyoffs',
            items: [{
                html: '',
                minWidth: 60
            }, {
                html: 'Buyoff',
                minWidth: 250
            }, {
                html: 'Partial %',
                minWidth: 100
            }, {
                html: 'Completed',
                minWidth: 120
            },
            {
                html: '',
                cls: 'opBuyoffTransparent',
                minWidth: 50
            }
            ]
        }],
        listeners: {
        initialize: function(me, eOpts) {
            CAMSApp.util.I18N.resolveStaticUIBindings(me); 
        },
        show: function (me, eOpts) {
            // Publish the screen id event.
            log('[OpBuyoff.show]');
            CAMSApp.app.fireEvent('setscreenfocus', this);
        },
    },
}
});
```

I have tried reading the View and the Container - but neither elements have doLayout() or refresh() functions.

Comment: Also - I only really need to edit the Container: 'tabOfBuyoffs'

Comment: What do you mean with refreshing the view ?

Comment: I am calling a Web Service and need to be able to refresh elements on the view after a successful call.  It is my understanding that there should be some doLayout() or refresh() function but neither work.

Comment: Ok, but what exact is/are things you want to refresh? Do you want to recreate all the items ? or you just want to change their inner HTMLs ?

Comment: I want to recreate all of the items.  I suppose I could go through and destroy them and then recreate them.  I just thought there might be a function I could call to do the work for me :)

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. You need to use `removeAll` method to remove all items inside a container, and re-add them.

Comment: Okay, thanks ardabeyazoglu

Comment: I don't understand why not tide the data to a store, dynamically.

this is the right way to do so

Answer (score 1):

The containers and panels do have a method called `update(Ext.AbstractComponent-method-update)` which can be used to update a view's HTML content.

Also, you can use XTemplate for creating the items and bind the panel to a store. In that case you won't have to manually remove and add all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
refresh: function() {
   // Ext.StoreMgr.get('stream').load();
   // here I'd like to reload the app instead
   // not just the store
      window.location.reload(); 
}
```